# Why some associations in hibernate are very unusal what the reason behind their unusualness

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I was going through the hibernate documentation and i got the following

***UNI = Unidirectional***  and ***Bi = BiDirectional***

```
                     OneToOne      OneToMany         ManyToOne       ManyToMany 
Uni                  ok                UNUSUAL       MOST COMMON      
Uni with Join Tbl    UNUSUAL                        Common whn optional
Bi                   COMMON        <------ Most Common ------------>  
Bi with Join Tbl   Possible bt Unusual
```

So If we have Person and Phone Table and i want only person to know all its phone not phone the same (his owner) , Why it is unusual ?

Or why some mapping is much preferred in its category(like in Uni , Uni with Join table , Bi, Bi with Join table)

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to ensure that your mappings are in sync with your schema as much as possible.

You give the example of a Person and PhoneNumber association as a uni-directional OneToMany mapping. This is not advised because the PhoneNumber table inevitably has a foreign key to the Person table. Therefore the PhoneNumber is very much aware of its owner. However, if you use a uni-directional mapping you are pretending that the PhoneNumber doesn't know which Person owns it. There is nothing to stop you doing this, as noted in the Hibernate annotations documentation.

The disadvantage of this approach is that when you add a PhoneNumber and a Person Hibernate must insert both records and then update the PhoneNumber to set the foreign key. Three statements. However, if you use a bi-directional link, Hibernate can insert the PhoneNumber with the foreign key already set. Only requiring two statements.